# replace the first result page from clistview with static page

Tags: php, sql, yii

My app db just went over 100 Gbs and it will crash soon.

I can save it, if i can replace the first result page of the CListView with a static page.

It's easier for the server to print a static page. And I can easily regenerate the static pages, daily as needed.

There is no code, because i can't figure out how to modify the ClistView to reach my goal, if posible;

The answer is found when using memmory allocation;

For those that know how to work with memmory, there is the term SENTINEL

when adding new data to a queue, you have find the right position for the data, and then insert it

by using the sentinels, you willalways have at least 2 elements in the queue

this is what i neeed to achive

i need to put a sentinel, before the first element of the clistview

i need to manipulate clistview; i just want to set the first page of the clistview, with my static page

maybe the pagination will be set to 40 elements, and my static page will have 1000 per page

but when the user hits page 2 or 3 or 4 ... clistview should list the next 40

for page 2, actually, clistview will list the first real results; everything gets pushed to the right

Comment: What do you want to show on your static page? If it's really a static page, then it won't even have a pagination there. Otherwhise it's not static anymore. In that case i wonder how you want to navigate to following pages.

Comment: I want to have the navigation activated even if the first page is static

Comment: Then you should not call that "static page". You will see a DB query on that page, because the pagination will always require 1 query to fetch the total count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [page caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.page) varying by `CListView`'s page index. Of course, this is not as fast as returning a static page but can increase a performance significantly.

**UPDATE**

In order to replace a link to first page in `CListView` you can override [createPageUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBasePager#createPageUrl-detail) method of [CLinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBasePager#createPageUrl-detail):

```
<?php
class StaticLinkPager extends CLinkPager
{
    public $firstPageUrl;

    protected function createPageUrl($page)
    {
        if ($page == 1)
            return $this->firstPageUrl;
        return parent::createPageUrl($page);
    }
}
```

and use it with your `CListView` setting its [pager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#pager-detail) property to:

```
array(
    'class' => 'StaticLinkPager',
    'firstPageUrl' => '/list-view-first-static-page.html'
)
```

Comment: I am using page caching; But is it possible to replace the first page ?

Comment: If you use page caching and if you can easily regenerate static content of first pages of `CListView` does it mean that you only need to replace a link to the first page in `CListView`'s pager?

Comment: you deserve a +1; your solution might be the best, even if i already use this and want more

Answer (score 2):

From your comment i guess you probably want something like this:

```
<?php if($dataProvider->pagination->currentPage==0): ?>
    <?php /* 
       Render your static content + a custom CLinkPager here.
       Feed $dataProvider->pagination as 'pages' into the link pager.
     */ ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <?php /* Render your listview here */ ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As i stated in my comment above you will still see 1 query to fetch the item count. You can't avoid this as long as you render the pagination also for your "static" content.

Comment: something like this; i have to create a fake pager